# PHP Post request not working local on or Heroku

Tags: php, postman

I can't get POST to work on my localhost using MAMP and when I upload it to Heroku it doesn't work either, my Localhost doesn't have a .htaccess file, the Herokuapp does.

This is the code:

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
?>
```

I am sending the POST with Postman, this is the response:

array(0) {
}
string(4) "POST"

Get is working just fine BTW.

$_REQUEST is working to.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot with the Postman configuration you have tried?

Comment: Can't upload pictures yet: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sJt7CrghZBdtZUqzp_sp7NtZsomDN6eB/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry for not being explicit enough. I was curious more about the target URL you post to and the body (tab) of the request from Postman (not the actual settings tab).
PS: you can use image hosting services like imgur.

Just as an FYI: POST params are not sent via query params appended to the URL, but as body of the request.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I tried adding a quick HTML form that would send a POST request to the same page and that does work.

This is the response:

```
array(1) { ["test"]=> string(4) "test" } string(4) "POST"
```